# Set the Actual Size option in the Ad Hoc Editor of Jasper

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

After creating a view from my topic in an adhoc editor, when I preview my view (Export as PDF), my report gets truncated.

> E.g:My View has 20 fields, when I export the same, I get only 5 or 6
>   depending on the width of the field selected.

In JasperReports-Server-User-Guide.pdf, to overcome this, they have said the following

> To prevent horizontal truncation of an Ad Hoc report when exported,
>   set the Actual Size option in the Ad Hoc Editor.

I tried setting the same, but I did not find the option on the adhoc editor.
I went to Adhoc Settings via Manage--> Server Settings and tried my luck.
But somehow the option to set the size is not available.
Can someone let me kow where is the option to set the size of the report to actual size in the adhoc editor.
I am using Jasper Reports Server 5.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate this is a rather old question but I came across this section of the user manual and couldn't find the setting (JasperReports 5.6) so contacted Jaspersoft Support for clarification.

> This function has been removed from ad hoc editor. The PDF exports are
>   actual size by default.
>
> To pick the size of the report created in ad hoc you can use ad hoc
>   templates instead of the feature mentioned in the doc. When you save
>   ad hoc report you can use custom ad hoc template and pick Actual Size
>   there. By default Actual size is used.